# how to execute jar file in hadoop platform in ubuntu?

Tags: java, eclipse, hadoop, mapreduce, hbase

I can create Mapreduce programme, so i can configure hadoop in eclipse. after i can create 1. mapper, 2. reducer, 3.mapreducerDriver
after i can create jar file with help of Makefile in shell command prompt, 
after i can use 
this command

```
 hadoop jar $ {JarFile} $ {MainFunc} input output
```

1. > make file
   >     JarFile = "Sample-0.1.jar"
   >   MainFunc = "mypack.Mapreduce"
   >   LocalOutDir = "/ tmp / output"

after i use

jar-cvf $ {Sample-0.1.jar}-C bin /. 
  jar file created , finally i can write this  command.

```
 hadoop jar $ {Sample-0.1.jar} $ {mypack.Mapreduce} input output
```

finally i get like this error will come in command prompt.

> bash: ${mypack.Mapreduce}: bad substitution

how can i solve this problem . pleasae help me

now i find sollution

```
hadoop jar $ {Sample-0.1.jar} mypack.Mapreduce input output
```

then hadoop will be run .

Comment: Why do you use "${...}"?

Comment: It's a `bad substitution` because `mypack.Mapreduce` is not a variable.  Just run it like they werent variables.  `hadoop jar Sample-0.1.jar mypack.Mapreduce input output`

Comment: **if i use like hadoop jar Sample-0.1.jar mypack.Mapreduce input output  i face this error **                                 `Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Error opening job jar: Sample-0.1.jar
 at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:90)
Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
 at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
 at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:127)
 at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:135)
 at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:72)
 at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:88)
`

Comment: It seems that your jar is not a valid zip file. How did you package this jar?

Comment: 1. i create make file for corresponding project location with   `hadoop@hadoop:~/workspace$ gedit makefile'  after i can create make file with help of this conetent `JarFile = "Sample-0.1.jar"
MainFunc = "mypack.Mapreduce"
LocalOutDir = "/ tmp / output"   `      and i create jar file from that make file `jar-cvf $ { Sample-0.1.ja } -C bin /.`   . after jar file created   name called `0.1.jar but jar name not come Sample-0.1.jar` . after only i use run using this command `hadoop@hadoop:~/workspace/second$ hadoop jar Sample-0.1.jar mypack.Mapreduce input output`

Answer (score 0):

Write a script like compile.sh

$ mkdir wordcount_classes

$ javac -classpath ${HADOOP_HOME}/hadoop-${HADOOP_VERSION}-core.jar -d wordcount_classes WordCount.java

$ jar -cvf /usr/joe/wordcount.jar -C wordcount_classes/ .

For reference: http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.0.4/mapred_tutorial.html

Comment: if i do something like that, in that case i'm getting exception classnotfound on running the jar using
hadoop jar myjar.jar MianClass input output


Exception is: both inner classnot found for mapper or reducer

Comment: does your Main class is within package, if yes use the package name along with class name.